# html tag with in ng-init

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-init

I am angularjs beginner. I was trying to do something like this:

```
    <div ng-init="elements=
        [
          {
            element:'<a herf='www.google.com'>google</a>'
          },
          {
            element:'<a herf='www.yahoo.com'>yahoo</a>'
          }
        ]">
          <div ng-repeat="item in elements">
              <p>{{item.element}}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
```

It doesn't work, I think it is because of the single quotes inside the a tag. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Good workaround is to move it to controller. that is the right way. `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.` Apart from that you have typo `herf` should be `href` and you cannot render html  just like that, you would need to use ng-bind-html with ng-sanitize.

Comment: Why would you even think of doing this...study some angular tutorials. Why try to pack html into an attribute when all you need is the array of url's and generate the `<a>` in `ng-repeat`

Comment: thanks for all the comments! I'm doing that because I'm trying to create a web page doesn't need controller... @PSL your demo seems disappeared

Comment: @LiangzeLu Demo? if at all using ng-repeat. look for quote wrapping href value, escape it `\'` and i dont know what version of angular you are using,  other than very very old version you would need to include `angular-sanitize` script after the angular and in your app add dependency `angular,module('app', ['ngSanitize'])` and use ng-bind-html in `p` i.e `<p ng-bind-html="item.element"></p>`

Comment: Not a best practice but even putting the data in $rootScope would make more sense. You don't need a controller to access `$rootScope`. Why no controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @PSL mentioned, you should move that logic into a controller:

```
$scope.elements = [
          {
            element:'<a href="www.google.com">google</a>'
          },
          {
            element:'<a href="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>'
          }
        ]
```

If you want to keep it in `ng-init`, the issue was that your `href='...'`, should be in double quotes like in the above code. In order to use double quotes, you need to escape them like this: `\"`. You also misspelled `href`.

From the AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."

Comment: should strip it down even more to text and url and build the html in ng-repeat

Comment: thanks for the help but escaping by \ doesn't work as well, it becomes a real string , not  a link

Comment: @LiangzeLu That is expected, guess you missed my last comment in your question. :)

Comment: @PSL thank for the help again, i do missed your comment, it really helps!